# json_each and json_each_text results with different column names

Tags: postgresql

I've just upgraded to *Postgresql 9.3beta*. When I apply **json_each** or **json_each_text** functions to a json column, the result is a set of rows with column names **'key'** and **'value'**.

Here's an example:

I have a table named `customers` and `education` column is of type `json`

Customers table is as follows:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | first_name | last_name | education                              |
 ---- ------------ ----------- ----------------------------------------
| 1  | Harold     | Finch     | {\"school\":\"KSU\",\"state\":\"KS\"}  |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | John       | Reese     | {\"school\":\"NYSU\",\"state\":\"NY\"} |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The query

```
select * from customers, json_each_text(customers.education) where value = 'NYSU'
```

returns a set of rows with the following column names

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | first_name | last_name | education                              | key    | value |
 ---- ------------ ----------- ---------------------------------------- -------- -------
| 2  | John       | Reese     | {\"school\":\"NYSU\",\"state\":\"NY\"} | school | NYSU  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

because `json_each_text` function returns the set of rows with `key` and `value` column names by default.

However, I want `json_each_text` to return custom column names such as `key1` and `key2`:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | first_name | last_name | education                              | key1    | value1 |
 ---- ------------ ----------- ---------------------------------------- -------- ---------
| 2  | John       | Reese     | {\"school\":\"NYSU\",\"state\":\"NY\"} | school  | NYSU   |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to get different column names like **'key1'** and **'value1'** after applying those functions?

Comment: Please provide sample data, the actual queries, and the exact results.

Comment: OK, I added an example. Is it clear now?

Comment: While I can theoretically imagine what's going on, we need, as Craig wrote, **sample data**. So that we can see what you're seeing.

Comment: I added some sample data, too.

Comment: Converted sample data to usable form here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5fb08/1 . It's against 9.2, but at least the sample data is converted to proper sql.

Comment: Does michaelpq's answer help you? If not... why? Details?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can solve that by using AS in FROM and SELECT clause:

```
postgres=# SELECT json_data.key AS key1,
                  json_data.value AS value1
           FROM customers, 
                json_each_text(customers.education) AS json_data
           WHERE value = 'NYSU';
  key1  | value1 
--------+--------
 school | NYSU
(1 row)
```

Comment: Puzzled ... don't you need to use `LATERAL` for that?

Comment: The question was how it is possible to get different column names after applying the functions... Did I miss smth?

Comment: No, just surprised that works. You shouldn't be able to refer to columns of one table in another entry in the same FROM clause without LATERAL. Aaah, here's why it works: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1TzD9T-0005bR-1H@gemulon.postgresql.org

Comment: It would be nice to mention that this uses an implicit lateral join. I had a hard time to understand how this works 